# При создании exeшника запросы отправляются некорректно

Tags: python, requests, pyinstaller

написал программу, которая отправляет запросы на сервер. При запуске через PyCharm все запросы отправляются корректно. Код ответа 200. И весь корректный ответ.
Но при запуске через не через виртуальную среду(имеется в виду venv используемую в PyCharm) или через ,скомпилированный с помощью pyinstaller, exeшник, код ответа меняется на 403. И защита сайта принимает запросы за спам. Использование прокси не помогает. НО если использовать локальный прокси от Burp Suite, то запросы все работает нормально.
Вопрос: Из-за чего ответ меняется? И как мне это исправить?

Отрывок из кода:

```
                    post_data = {'text': '%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82', 'options': 4}                    
                    url = f'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1/tr.json/translate?id={self.id}-2-0&srv=tr-text&lang=ru-en&reason=paste&format=text&yu={yu}&yum={yum}'
                    if spravka != '':
                        url = f'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1/tr.json/translate?id={self.id}-2-0&srv=tr-text&lang=ru-en&reason=paste&format=text&yu={yu}&yum={yum}&sprvk={spravka}'
                    print(url)
                    headers2 = CaseInsensitiveDict()
                    headers2["Host"] = "translate.yandex.net"
                    headers2["Connection"] = "close"
                    headers2["Content-Length"] = "39"
                    headers2["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
                    headers2["sec-ch-ua-platform"] = '"Windows"'
                    headers2["sec-ch-ua-mobile"] = "?0"
                    headers2["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    headers2["Accept"] = "*/*"
                    headers2["Origin"] = "https://translate.yandex.ru"
                    headers2["Sec-Fetch-Site"] = "cross-site"
                    headers2["Sec-Fetch-Mode"] = "cors"
                    headers2["Sec-Fetch-Dest"] = "empty"
                    headers2["Referer"] = "https://translate.yandex.ru/?lang=ru-en&text=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82"
                    headers2["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate"
                    headers2["Accept-Language"] = "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
                    res = requests.post(url, data=post_data, headers=headers2, verify=False, cookies={})
```

P.S. Переменный yu, yum, self.id, spravka получаются выше в программе. С ними все корректно.
P.S2. requests в обоях средах одной версии
UPD:
Текс ошибки 403:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html>

<head>
    <title>403</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #000;
        background-color: #fff
    }
    
    .header {
        height: 48px
    }
    
    .header__logo {
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 130px;
        height: 48px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-indent: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center bottom
    }
    
    .header__code {
        font-size: 32px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 76px;
        height: 48px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #999
    }
    
    .header__logo_lang_ru {
        background-image: url(//yastatic.net/islands/_/5vJOTgN-leXxtlxIFPiM-vfC24o.png)
    }
    
    .header__logo_lang_en {
        background-image: url(//yastatic.net/islands/_/fGdVzvAAq7J8px5LpiysN6M_sy8.png)
    }
    
    .content {
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 20px 0 30px;
        padding-left: 25px
    }
    
    .content__h1 {
        font-size: 21px;
        font-weight: 400
    }
    
    .footer {
        line-height: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 0 25px;
        border-top: 1px solid #eee
    }
    
    .footer__copyright {
        font-size: 13px
    }
    
    .link {
        color: #44b
    }
    
    .link:hover {
        color: #e00
    }
    </style>\n
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="captcha.min.css" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="captcha.ie.min.css"/><![endif]-->\n</head>

<body>
    <div class=\ 'header\'>\n <a class="header__logo header__logo_lang_en" href="//www.yandex.com/">Yandex</a>\n
        <div class=\ 'header__code\'>403</div>
    </div>
    <div class=\ 'content\'>\n
        <h1 class="content__h1">Access to&nbsp;our service has been temporarily blocked.</h1>
        <p>Your computer may be&nbsp;infected with a&nbsp;virus, which is&nbsp;sending repeated requests to&nbsp;Yandex.
            <br>We&nbsp;recommend you scan your computer with an&nbsp;antivirus or&nbsp;contact your network administrator.</p>
        <p>If&nbsp;you come across any problems or&nbsp;would like to&nbsp;ask a&nbsp;question, please do&nbsp;not hesitate to&nbsp;contact our Support service using the <a class="link" href=\ 'https://yandex.com/support/smart-captcha/?unique_key=cd5d469e-89d39849-95a729b0-63093702\' onclick="ym(15897442, \'reachGoal\', \'support_complain\', { \'req_id\': \'\' }); return true;">contact us&nbsp;form</a>.</p>\n
        <p>cd5d469e-89d39849-95a729b0-63093702</p>\n</div>
    <div class=\ 'footer\'><span class=\ 'footer__copyright\'>\xc2\xa9&nbsp;\xd0\xaf\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81</span></div>
    <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(m, e, t, r, i, k, a) {
        m[i] = m[i] || function() {
            (m[i].a = m[i].a || []).push(arguments)
        };
        m[i].l = 1 * new Date();
        k = e.createElement(t), a = e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], k.async = 1, k.src = r, a.parentNode.insertBefore(k, a)
    })(window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym");
    ym(15897442, "init", {
        clickmap: true,
        trackLinks: true,
        accurateTrackBounce: true,
        webvisor: true,
        ut: "noindex",
        params: {
            "service": "translate",
            "req_id": "",
            "ident_type": "1",
            "unique_key": "cd5d469e-89d39849-95a729b0-63093702"
        }
    });
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/15897442?ut=noindex" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div>
    </noscript>
    <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 403 обычно идет с текстом ошибки

Comment: приложите его, иначе вам тут не помогут

Comment: @finally Спасибо, исправил